# SwiftNativeNSStringBase error in Apache error log after update to MacOS Sonoma

Tags: php, macos, apache

I have recently updated my Mac to Sonoma (14.2.1), and I'm running several websites on my local machine with Apache/PHP/MySql via Macports. Everything runs fine, I just can't get one of the local websites to work.

This is in the Apache error_log:
`+[__SwiftNativeNSStringBase initialize] may have been in progress in another thread when fork() was called.`
`+[__SwiftNativeNSStringBase initialize] may have been in progress in another thread when fork() was called. We cannot safely call it or ignore it in the fork() child process. Crashing instead. Set a breakpoint on objc_initializeAfterForkError to debug.`
`[core:notice] [pid 6373] AH00052: child pid 6914 exit signal Abort trap (6)`

A common solution seems to be to put this in the `.zshrc`, but it's not working for me:
`export OBJC_DISABLE_INITIALIZE_FORK_SAFETY=YES`

I have also added `export DISABLE_SPRING=true`, which a is another recommendation, but it doesn't work for me either. The website is not loading anymore.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Please don't use unrelated tags (removed [tag:python])

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found it. This is an issue with the `gettext` module in PHP-FPM, as mentioned here: https://github.com/php/php-src/issues/11818#issuecomment-1693882303

Summary: Don't just do `_('Translate me')` without setting `putenv('LC_ALL=en_US')` or any other locale.